# SyntaxHighlighter extra spaces

Tags: java, html, syntax-highlighting

I'm using SyntaxHighlighter, so problem is that first line always prints with extra spaces independently of code language

string:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

preview with SH:

import java.util.HashMap;

html from page:

```
<div class="line number1 index0 alt2"><code class="java spaces">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</code><code class="java keyword">import</code> <code class="java plain">java.util.HashMap;</code></div>
```

And it's only for first page for all bushes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SH is working properly. They don't add spaces to anything. (if you meant indentation, try to reduce padding-left in CSS)

Comment: properly? are you kidding? what about `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Comment: The non-breaking spaces are not added by SH, something's wrong with the way you submit or store the code.

Comment: the problem was in my code formatting in IDE. response has the same spaces in pre tag.